# bash: how do I substring all but what is in single quotes?

Tags: regex, bash, substring

Say, the following command:
**less some_filename | grep -w 'some_text'** 
 gives the following output:

```
  some_text =  'x.y.z';
```

being x,y,z numbers like 1.12.5 for instance, how do I strip the output to just

**x.y.z**        ?

Should be possible with some regex or sed/awk or so, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find that when using `grep`, `cut` is my friend. You can cut out characters or fields. In this case, you'd want something like:

`echo "some_text = 'x.y.z'" | cut -d\' -f2`

The `-d` parameter specifies the delimiter (escaped here) and the `-f` specifies the field number (1-indexed).

If your data might be on different fields, then you'll have to come up with a regexp that matches the part you want. Like

`cat file | grep -o x\.y\.z`

The `-o` to `grep` means to only return the part that matches.

Comment: Among all the things I've tried the 'cut' option was missing. This one works for me too and both like what I was looking for and understandable. 

Thank you.

Comment: @slibbe Please check this answer as "this helps me"

Answer (score 0):

```
echo " some_text =  '12.3.012';" | sed -r "s/[^']+'([.0-9]+)'\s*;/\1/"
```

Comment: And thanks again :) This one also works for me. 

So now I have three options, two along the line of what I was looking for and a easy to understand third new option.

Answer (score 0):

by awk:

```
kent$  echo "some_text =  'x.y.z';"|awk -F"'" '{print $2}'
x.y.z
```

and actually you can also do something on your grep line. e.g.

```
less somefile | grep -Po "(?<=some_text =  ')[^']*(?=')"
```

Comment: Thank you. The first part does the trick for me.
The grep option doesn't for some reason, though.

Answer (score 0):

This will do both the line matching and content extraction:

```
awk -F"'" '/some_text/{print $2}' some_filename
```

For example:

```
[me@home]$ cat some_filename 
random data 
some_text =  'x.y.z'; 
another_text = '1.2.3.4';

[me@home]$ awk -F"'" '/some_text/{print $2}' some_filename 
x.y.z
```

Brief description of the `awk` command:

- `-F"'"` : Change the field separator to`'`. This will effectively split a string like "`some_text = 'x.y.z'`" to 3 fields - "`some_text =`", "`x.y.x`", and "`;`"
- `/some_text/` : match only lines that contain "`some_text`"
- `{print $2}` : for each matching line, print the second field (in this case, "`x.y.z`")

Comment: Thx. 

Even though it can be very usefull to look for an answer myself in this case I should have started asking a bit faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Same as  [Prince John Wesley solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847458/bash-how-do-i-substring-all-but-what-is-in-single-quotes/7847534#7847534), only plus to search `some_text`.

```
sed -n "/some_text/ s@.*'\([^']*\)'.*@\1@p"
```